# What font is used in this banner?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, text

I need to know what font is used in this banner, which comes from the [FAO website](http://www.fao.org/investment/investment-policy/en/).

[image: Banner]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Graphic Design SE. Have you tried http://whatthefont.com/?

Comment: Nice tool but don't give me a good answer in this case :-(

Comment: Myriad is very close, but the y and a are slightly different: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NpJsG.png

Comment: The single-story 'g' and double-story 'a' are driving me crazy! 'a' glyphs that look like that tend to have double-story 'g' glyphs. [Alright Sans](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/okay-type/alright-sans/) is an...alright...choice, but it's not correct.

Comment: Myriad was my guess on first glance too, but that is a different y.

Comment: Here's a [normal size](http://i.imgur.com/Ct7n9kt.png) and [enhanced](http://i.imgur.com/sclNhEoh.png) version for use with whatthefont. Using this I was able to determine that it was Lucida Sans.

Answer (score 8):

Found it, I think!  It's [**Lucida Sans**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/lucida-sans/).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks right, well done!

Comment: Ahh, great match! I had a feeling it had to be a relatively mainstream font...